# Class Parameterized Constructor in a class

Tags: c#, constructor

I want know if its possible to have this parameterized constructor.

Heres the class example

```
  class Example
  public string name;
  public int age;
```

//parameterized

```
  public Example(string name2, int   age2)
  name = name2;
  age = age2;
```

Form

Button_Clicked

```
Example exam1 = new Example (Textbox1.Text, int.Parse(Textbox2.Text));

MessageBox.Show("Info" + exam1.Example().ToString());
```

I wanted to work out an parameterized constructor in which my declared variables would catch or get and store both textboxes values.

Comment: What's the particular problem? Just add such constructor. Constructors are just methods.

Comment: `exam1.Example().ToString()` makes no sense. There is no method `Example()` in your `Example` class.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh: No, constructors aren't "just methods" - they have quite different semantics in a number of ways.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree with you. But declaring constructor with parameters and pass parameters to constructor does not differ from other methods. The main problem in that question is not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic stuff. You could have just googled it...

But since I am making an answer, I'll give you the code.

I want to make a class for storing, let's say... A full name and age. Let's call it `Person`. Of course, you will have to make a new class `public class Person { }`.

Now, in the class, you have to make variables you will use for storing data. The convention is to add an underscore before the names. I want to call them `_Age` which is an `Int32` value (or simply `int`) and a string value, `_Name`.

Make sure that the variables are set to `private`, because you don't want other threads to access these.

Next, you make the constructor. Since we named our class `Person`, and it takes two parameters, it would look something like this. `public Person(string fullName, int age) { }`, just like a method, but you don't give what type.

In the `public Person()` thread, you should tell what is to be done to the values you receive. In this case, we are going to store them in our variables we made before (I mean the `_Age` and the `_Name`). So you can set the value of `_Age` as the `age` parameter in the constructor and `_Name` as the `fullName` parameter.

And then, you can do whatever you want with `get` and `set`.

Here's a class file:

```
public class Person
{
    private string _Name;
    private int _Age;

    public Person(string fullName, int age)
    {
        _Name = name;
        _Age = fullName;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    public string Age
    {
        get { return _Age; }
        set { _Age = value; }
    }
}
```